# Line continuation in command substitution

Tags: tcl

Given this short code snippet:

```
set a [list \
  foo \
  bar
]
```

When I remove the `\` after `list` I get `invalid command name "foo"` and when I remove the `\` after `foo` I get `invalid command name "bar"`.

However, the code as I have put it runs fine and I do not get something like `invalid command name "]"`.

Why is no `\` required after `bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of a `[`…`]` sequence is actually a script, not just a command (though people mostly don't take advantage of this because they're not crazy). Putting extra blank lines at the end of the script doesn't change what the result of the script is: it's the result of the last command in the script (unless the script is empty, when it is the empty string).

Leaving the `\` characters out means that there's a multi-command script in there, which is legal (though you've not created the commands `foo` or `bar`). Having them in means that you've got an overall script that is equivalent to:

```
set a [list  foo  bar
]
```

With exactly those spaces. That's usually practically identical to this:

```
set a [list foo bar]
```

But the difference is there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error message because the recursive evaluation ends at the close bracket. It's not part of the command substitution script. As far as the recursive evaluation in the command substitution is concerned, that's just a list command with some white space following it.